# In what condition we should use pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

```
/* set *largest_pt to the largest element pointed to by the array */
void find_largest(int **A, int A_size, int *largest_pt) {
    *largest_pt = **A;
    for (int i = 1; i < A_size; i++) {
        if (*A[i] > *largest_pt) {
            *largest_pt = *A[i];
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I don't know why we use pointer to pointer `**A`. Can we use pointer `*A` instead?

Comment: Hint: pointers are passed by value too.

Comment: Is this the only function in the context? Are there other functions with similar interface? Keeping a set of interfaces intuitively similar might be a reason, but only if there actually IS a set, not only a single. That is why the context is important.

Comment: If `A` is an *array* of pointers to `int`, then when you pass it as an argument to the function, the expression is converted to a pointer to the first element, so what the function receives is a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: @GovindParmar Please elaborate, I do not see where you are going with that hint.

Comment: @John Bode Thank you! I think that reasonable.

Comment: This function is broken from inception *unless* the intent is to traverse the first *column* in a 2D matrix implemented as an array of pointers to rows. The operator precedence of `*A[i]` is very likely not what you think it is, as `[]` has higher precedence than `*` in the C language. Therefore, the expression `*A[i]` evaluates as `*(A[i])`, which means "get the i'th pointer in the sequence of pointers rooted at `A`, then dereference that  pointer to get the sought-after value". I see no reason to use multi-indirection in this code, and a plethora of reasons *not* to if not the case I cited.